# Why I can't create azurerm_app_service connection?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

## Azurerm provider version

3.35.0

## Target resource

azurerm_app_service_connection

## Terraform file

write brief

```
module "app_service" {
  source               = "../../modules/app_service"
  name                 = var.name
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "serviceconnector" {
  name               = "serviceconnector"
  app_service_id     = module.app_service.id
  target_resource_id = data.azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db.id
  client_type        = "django"
  authentication {
    type   = "secret"
    name   = var.db_uname
    secret = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.value
  }
}

data "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "db" {
  name                = "postgre"
  resource_group_name = "rg"
}
```

## Output Error message

```
Error: creating Scoped Linker (Resource Uri: "/subscriptions/<id>/resourceGroups/app/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/app_service"
│ Linker Name: "serviceconnector"): performing LinkerCreateOrUpdate: servicelinker.ServiceLinkerClient#LinkerCreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="TargetTypeNotSupported" Message="Target resource type MICROSOFT.DBFORPOSTGRESQL/FLEXIBLESERVERS is not supported."
│ 
│   with azurerm_app_service_connection.serviceconnector,
│   on app_service.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "serviceconnector":
│   10: resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "serviceconnector" {
│ 
│ creating Scoped Linker (Resource Uri:
│ "/subscriptions/<id>/resourceGroups/app/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/app_service"
│ Linker Name: "serviceconnector"): performing LinkerCreateOrUpdate:
│ servicelinker.ServiceLinkerClient#LinkerCreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error:
│ Code="TargetTypeNotSupported" Message="Target resource type MICROSOFT.DBFORPOSTGRESQL/FLEXIBLESERVERS is not
│ supported."
```

## I want to ask

I updated `azurerm` provider to 3.35.0 by see this info.[azurerm_app_service_connection: Expected type object but found type string](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19439)

Why return "TargetTypeNotSupported" this message.
It seems to supported as long as I saw.
[azurerm_app_service_connection](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_connection)
It's my fault? or bug?

Comment: I have tested this in my local and landed up with error `targettypenotsupported`  if we want to create a service connection to postgressql flexible server db with app service then db should be declared using `resource` block only since as per this terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_flexible_server_database) we dont have any definition to use  `data` block to create a connection with existing postgres sql flexible  server db as shown in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/1J7quAS.png)

Comment: thank you! 
I'm misunderstood target_resource_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this in my local and landed up with error `targettypenotsupported`.

If we want to create a service connection to postgressql flexible server db with app service then db should be declared using `resource` block only since as per this terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_flexible_server_database) we dont have any definition to use `data`block to create a connection with existing postgres sql flexible server db as shown in this image

[image]

Comment: thank you!
I was solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same [github terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19439) which you added in my environment, with the authentication type as "Secret" and received the same error as shown:

[image]

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues), there appears to be a problem with the "secret authentication type" from the Terraform provider API. As a result, I updated it as follows and it worked for me successfully:

```bash
authentication {
    type   = "systemAssignedIdentity"
  }
```

***main.tf:***

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.35.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
    features {
      resource_group {
        prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
      }
   }
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "xxxxRG"
  location = "xxxxx"
}
resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "main" {
  name                             = "xxxxxserver"
  resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                         = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  administrator_login              = "xxxxxuser"
  administrator_login_password     = "<Password of server>"
  backup_retention_days            = 7 // As per your requirements
  sku_name                         = "GP_Gen5_2"
  version                          = "11"
  storage_mb                       = 5120
  public_network_access_enabled    = false
  ssl_enforcement_enabled          = true
  ssl_minimal_tls_version_enforced = "TLS1_2"
}
resource "azurerm_postgresql_database" "main" {
  name                = "xxxxdb"
  server_name         = azurerm_postgresql_server.main.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_postgresql_server.main.resource_group_name
  charset             = "utf8"
  collation           = "und-x-icu"
}
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "main" {
  name                = "xxxxxserviceplan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
  os_type             = "Linux"
}
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "main" {
  name                = "xxxxxwebapp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.main.id
  site_config {}
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_connection" "main" {
  name               = "xxxxxserviceconnector"
  app_service_id     = azurerm_linux_web_app.main.id
  target_resource_id = azurerm_postgresql_database.main.id
  client_type        = "springBoot"
  authentication {
    type   = "systemAssignedIdentity"
  }
}
```

***Output***:-

***Executed*** `terraform init`

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform apply`:

[image]

***Alternatively, If the requirement is only with the secret authentication type in your environment then you can*** [create an app service connection by calling API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/serviceconnector/linker/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#security) (JSON request).

Comment: I worked with below.

I have tested this in my local and landed up with error targettypenotsupported if we want to create a service connection to postgressql flexible server db with app service then db should be declared using resource block only since as per this terraform documentation we dont have any definition to use data block to create a connection with existing postgres sql flexible server db as shown in this image – 
VenkateshDodda-MSFT